# Where expiry date is 7 days ago, and there are no others active

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

So I'm checking to see that a "tag" has expired 7 days ago. But I also want to make sure that there *aren't any other tags* that are still "valid" within the same query. So, if there are other tags connected to the user that `expiry_date` is still in the future, ignore that tag.

I've got the first part working fine:

```
$seven_days_ago_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')) . ' 00:00:01';
$seven_days_ago_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')) . ' 23:59:59';

$expired_tags = DB::table('tags')
        ->leftJoin('users', 'tags.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->leftJoin('pets', 'pets.id', '=', 'tags.pet_id')
        ->where('tags.active', '=', 1)
        ->whereBetween('tags.expiry_date', array($seven_days_ago_start, $seven_days_ago_end))
        ->select('users.id', 'users.username', 'users.email', 'users.first_name', 'tags.serial_number')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe like this

```
$expired_tags = DB::table('tags')
            ->leftJoin('tags as t', function($join) use ($seven_days_ago_end){
                $join->on('tags.user_id','=','t.user_id')->where('t.expiry_date','>',$seven_days_ago_end);
            })
            ->join('users', function($join){
                $join->on('tags.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->whereNull('t.expiry_date');
            })
            ->leftJoin('pets', 'pets.id', '=', 'tags.pet_id')
            ->where('tags.active', '=', 1)
            ->whereBetween('tags.expiry_date', array($seven_days_ago_start, $seven_days_ago_end))
            ->select('users.id', 'users.username', 'users.email', 'users.first_name', 'tags.serial_number')
            ->get();
```

Comment: There's no reference to "seven_days_ago_start" within your query.

Comment: I added a start and end for day.

Comment: Sadly this does not produce any results for me.

Comment: See updated. I was incorrectly using two where clauses. Basically eliminating all records.

Comment: This is still not producing anything for me. I've modified the tags in my user account so that there should be a result, but I'm not getting anything.

Comment: Okay, now I get a result. However, it's ignoring all tags in the case where one has expired 7 days ago and another expires in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a subquery to pull the tags that are still active:

```
SELECT tags.id
FROM tags
WHERE tags.expiry_date > $seven_days_ago_end;
```

Then, use a `NOT IN` operator to make sure you don't pull those tags. You can put this condition in the join:

```
JOIN users ON tags.user_id = users.id AND tags.id NOT IN(...);
```

I am not experienced with Laravel, so I'm not sure how to convert it for you, but I hope this puts you on the right track.

Comment: I think this is the way I need to go, but I'm having a hard time figuring the best way to write that using QB.

Comment: @dcolumbus maybe it would be easier not to do it in the join, can you put it in a where clause? `->where('tags.id', 'not in', '...')` ? I wish I could provide more assistance in writing it in QB, I'm sorry.